# Unable to configure GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Spring Boot application which is connected with Google Cloud's MySQL database

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform

After doing other required configurations when I am trying to run my springboot application from my local machine by connecting with google cloud's mysql database, getting below exception.

**Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:125)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:125)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:97)
at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(CoreSocketFactory.java:392)
... 173 common frames omitted**

I have tried multiple ways by refering google cloud's documentation, but still having same issue.

**Approach-1:**
After generating google application's credentials, downloaded the .json file and placed inside resources folder of the project. Then tried to configure inside pom.xml like below:-

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <image>
            <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
            </image>
            <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>true</executable>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>../resources/demoapp-z75645782m5h.json</GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration> 
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Approach-2:**
After generating google application's credentials, downloaded the .json file and kept at any random location in my local machine. Then provided that location as file's path, as one of the environmental variables, like below:-
[Variable name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
Variable value: C:\Users\Public\Google_Cloud_Credentials\demoapp-z75645782m5h.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOAx7.png)

Both the above approaches are not working for me.

Comment: Where should run your application at the end? On Google Cloud?